# ASP .Net WorldPay Integration

Tags: asp.net, transactions

I'm wondering whether anyone has any useful information on integrating WorldPay into an ASP.Net web application? I'm looking to take payments for a fixed amount directly from the web site, no shopping cart required.

Essentially I'm just looking for some reference source code or a good article covering what's required. Does WorldPay support web services or REST etc?

Cheers,

Brian.

Answer (score 1):

Include on your "checkout" page the following form (with the relevant values):

```
<form action="https://select.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="instId" value="<your worldpay installation ID>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="<a reference for this transaction>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<the amount to pay>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="<your currency code i.e. GBP>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="desc" value="<a description of this transaction>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="testMode" value="<worldpay's test mode ID>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<customer's name>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="address" value="<customer's full address>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="postcode" value="<customer's postcode>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="country" value="<country code i.e. GB>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<customer's email address>" />
</form>
```

Then in your Worldpay profile (on their website once you've registered) you'll have an option for postback URL (can't remember the exact label) which will POST the following keys to this URL (so it'll be a page on your website that receives this) containing the result of the transaction:

```
string wp_rawauthcode = Request.Form["rawauthcode"];
string wp_amount = Request.Form["amount"];
string wp_installation = Request.Form["installation"];
string wp_tel = Request.Form["tel"];
string wp_address = Request.Form["address"];
string wp_mc_log = Request.Form["mc_log"];
string wp_rawauthmessage = Request.Form["rawauthmessage"];
string wp_authamount = Request.Form["authamount"];
string wp_amountstring = Request.Form["amountstring"];
string wp_cardtype = Request.Form["cardtype"];
string wp_avs = Request.Form["avs"];
string wp_cost = Request.Form["cost"];
string wp_currency = Request.Form["currency"];
string wp_testmode = Request.Form["testmode"];
string wp_authamountstring = Request.Form["authamountstring"];
string wp_fax = Request.Form["fax"];
string wp_transstatus = Request.Form["transstatus"];
string wp_compname = Request.Form["compname"];
string wp_postcode = Request.Form["postcode"];
string wp_authcost = Request.Form["authcost"];
string wp_desc = Request.Form["desc"];
string wp_cartid = Request.Form["cartid"];
string wp_transid = Request.Form["transid"];
string wp_callbackpw = Request.Form["callbackpw"];
string wp_sessionId = Request.Form["MC_sessionId"];
string wp_CusId = Request.Form["MC_cusId"];
string wp_authmode = Request.Form["authmode"];
string wp_name = Request.Form["name"];
string wp_shop = Request.Form["MC_shop"];
string wp_wafMerchMessage = Request.Form["wafMerchMessage"];
string wp_authentication = Request.Form["authentication"];
string wp_email = Request.Form["email"];
```

Perform some basic validation here like making sure the installation ID (wp_installation) matches what you expect, and the amount, currency etc before setting the order status to "Paid" or something.

Answer (score -2):

Brian, I would suggest you check with WorldPay. Most merchant account gateway providers offer an API, a sandbox for testing, documentation and even code examples. I've not integrated with WorldPay specifically, but I have found this to be the case with other providers.