# Pass form variables on to second postback...asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to postback to the server, perform a function, and then continue that postback on to an external place? (ie, to a payment system)

(the scenario is clicking a button to place an order, mark it as sent, then send them off to the payment page (there are form variables that needs to be sent to the payment screen as well))

Comment: I'd double check the payment page to see if you can pass those variables on the URL, which would probably make your life so much nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (probably) use [`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08za4s98.aspx) and send the posted variables to the external page as part of the querystring.

The variables will then be visible in the browser's address bar, but this is no less secure than posted form variables, just a bit uglier.

You need to ensure that the variables are tamper-proof regardless of how they're submitted to the payment page. You should consult the payment provider's documentation to figure out how to do this.

Comment: This is how I ended up doing it, with the md5 hash to ensure it hadn't been tampered with

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking "continue that postback", if you want to send these values to a payment page, you can store them in session state and access them on that payment page. It's not a "postback" if you're transferring control to a different page.

**UPDATE**

Since it's Worldpay payment service, you need to check their API and perhaps contact them.

[Securely submitting form data to Worldpay using ASP.NET](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_22592214.html)

[Google Search on ASP.NET and Worldpay](http://bit.ly/e0Mu6c)

[Similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618690/asp-net-worldpay-integration)

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but I think the the payment page might be a completely different webserver under the control of a 3rd party, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: @Greg, good point +1... @Paul, can you be more specific re the external payment system? Is it PayPal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do that.   Once the postback loads, output an HTML form that occurs outside of the default ASP.net form, and use javascript to automatically submit that form once the page has loaded.

You could do this entirely as a javascript solution (and update the div outside the asp.net form) or you could overwrite the rendering method of the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

A work around if the two are on different page. This is just skeleton

```
try
{
   Response.Redirect(To your order page);
   Process your data
   try
   {
        Response.redirect to WorldPay
        Do  Payment

   }
   catch
   {
       to original page
   }

}
Catch
{
     Reposne.Redirect to origin page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use the URL API to accomplish this.  I'm not sure if this is the right part of the API though.
http://www.rbsworldpay.com/support/kb/bg/htmlredirect/rhtml.html#rhtml5207.html

Edit: I see they are passing the price on the query string.  Hopefully that's not susceptible to manipulation....